# How can i solve ImportError: Using the `Trainer` with `PyTorch` requires `accelerate>=0.20.1` when using Huggingface's TrainArguments?

Tags: python, nlp, importerror, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm using the `transformers` library in Google colab, and
When i am using TrainingArguments from transformers library i'm getting Import error with this  code:

```
from transformers import TrainingArguments

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir = "/content/our-model",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size= 64,
    per_device_eval_batch_size = 16,
    num_train_epochs = 2,
    weight_decay = 0.01,
    evaluation_strategy = "epoch",
    save_strategy = "epoch",
    load_best_model_at_end = True,
    push_to_hub = False
)
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
<ipython-input-28-0518ea5ff407> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 from transformers import TrainingArguments
----> 2 training_args = TrainingArguments(
      3     output_dir = "/content/our-model",
      4     learning_rate=2e-5,
      5     per_device_train_batch_size= 64,

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/training_args.py in _setup_devices(self)
   1670         if not is_sagemaker_mp_enabled():
   1671             if not is_accelerate_available(min_version="0.20.1"):
-> 1672                 raise ImportError(
   1673                     "Using the `Trainer` with `PyTorch` requires `accelerate>=0.20.1`: Please run `pip install transformers[torch]` or `pip install accelerate -U`"
   1674                 )

ImportError: Using the `Trainer` with `PyTorch` requires `accelerate>=0.20.1`: Please run `pip install transformers[torch]` or `pip install accelerate -U
```

I already tried pip install for 0.20.1 version of accelerate and pip install transformers[torch]
and both didn't worked.

Comment: What the output of `import sys; sys.executable`?

Comment: Also it looks like you're using sagemaker, what is the sagemaker command you're using?

Comment: @alvas this is the output of sys.executable:  /usr/bin/python3

Comment: @alvas I don't know what is a sagemaker command is but if it would be helpful I'm using google colab for running the code.

Comment: Yes knowing that you're running in Google colab is helpful. Which model are you looking to run particularly? And are you open to installing the library at a fixed version? Or you just want the code to work regardless of luvrai version?

Comment: @alvas "savasy/bert-base-turkish-sentiment-cased" this is the model I'm using. I'm importing transformers library and the other libraries directly without specify any version. The version is not important for me just i want it works. Btw thank you for helps.

Comment: Glad to help. Hope the answers help fix your issues.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you're not particular about which transformers and accelerate version to tie to, then do this to use the most up-to-date version in Google Colab:

```
! pip install -U accelerate
! pip install -U transformers
```

Then the issue you are having with accelerate should auto-resolve itself.

Note:

- Underspecifying `pip install -U transformers` instead of `pip install transformers[pytorch]` might be easier since that's what most of the users do and the developers of the library will make sure that the basic pip works with the common functions and class like `TrainingArguments`
- Instead of specifying accelerate to the `pip install accelerate>=0.20.1`, if you have no particular need to fixed the version, automatically upgrading to the latest version might get you more stability when using the library, esp. with "hot"/"trending" libraries that are constantly changing (almost) daily.

---

If further debugging is necessary, i.e. if the above didn't work. To check your transformers and accelerate version, do this:

```
import accelerate

accelerate.__version__
```

Most probably you might have an `ImportError` at the first line if accelerate is not already installed when you installed `transformers`.

And then if the first line works and the 2nd line is not outputting a version `>=0.20.1`, then that is the cause of your issue.

The current versions to-date (July 2023) are:

```
import accelerate
import transformers

transformers.__version__, accelerate.__version__
```

[out]:

```
('4.30.1', '0.21.0')
```

Here's an example notebook with the model that you wish to use as per the comments in your question, https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1D79AjHMeE6HAZC-g2S83baTgsHtDUu5i?usp=sharing

---

If the error persist after the `pip install ...`, try restarting the runtime.

If you can't find the buttons to press to restart, try this in the cell [Restart kernel in Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55005114/restart-kernel-in-google-colab) then re-run the cells for `import ...`

```
import os
os._exit(00)
```

Comment: after two pip installs, restarting the runtime works for me

Answer (score 0):

If using a virtual environment configured by `Conda`, installation is sufficient.

```
conda install accelerate
```