# troubleshooting PyTorch and Hugging Face's Pre-trained deBerta Model on Windows 11 with an RTX 3070 GPU

Tags: pytorch, nlp, gpu, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I'm running Windows 11 on my desktop, which has an NVIDIA RTX 3070 GPU. I'm working on an NLP task using Hugging Face's AutoModelForSequenceClassification and I want to utilize my GPU for training. I've successfully installed PyTorch 1.9.0 with CUDA 11.1 and confirmed that CUDA is available on my system.

However, when I try to run my script, I encounter an ImportError suggesting that I need to install the accelerate library. When I attempt to do so, it not only fails but also replaces my existing `PyTorch 1.9.0` installation with version 2.1.0. I've tried various commands like pip install transformers[torch] and `pip install accelerate -U`, but they all result in the same issue.

The error message also indicates that accelerate requires at least PyTorch 1.10, but I can't find a compatible CUDA version for my RTX 3070.

Does anyone have a solution for running a proper installation of transformers + torch + accelerate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i solve ImportError: Using the \`Trainer\` with \`PyTorch\` requires \`accelerate>=0.20.1\` when using Huggingface's TrainArguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76448287/how-can-i-solve-importerror-using-the-trainer-with-pytorch-requires-accele)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and the downvote. But I am afraid the problem is not solved buy your answer. In my question I said it clearly I installed accelerate, the problem is "it erased my stable torch 1.9.0+cu111 in the end." Which means i can't use CUDA anymore. I would love to "leverage my GPU in the machine." . This is why your solution doesn't help. And perhaps it is worth thinking twice before casting a downvote for the good of the forum.

Comment: I didn’t downvote your question, I just correctly tagged it. I saw someone else cast the vote while I was editing it. So please keep your assumptions to yourself. For the good of the site ([SO] most definitely is not a forum)

Comment: I m sorry if it wasn't you. I take it back. There were only a few views when I wrote. The probability for both being done by the same account was too high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed PyTorch on multiple combinations (OS+Hardware).

I have installed PyTorch successfully using those commands (in a virtual environment):

- `%pip install --upgrade transformers`
- `%pip install --upgrade torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117`
- `%pip install accelerate (will take latest at the time of writing @0.23.0)`
- `%pip install evaluate datasets`

These helped me kick-start any of the projects which require HuggingFace. I hope it helps you.

Comment: It works like charm. Thank you very much, now my stuck project regains momentum again! For all those having the same question, please remember to reset your kernel after following the installation above.